# Cómo colocar una variable dentro de un href PHP

Tags: php, html

quizá esta pregunta sea una obviedad para muchos pero llevo más de 15 días sin poder resolverlo.
Estoy haciendo un sitio básico en php, el sitio tiene un nav bar fixed y me gustaría colocar un botón dropdown para elegir los idiomas.
Los idiomas los estoy colocan en carpetas con la inicial de cada idioma ejemplo en para inglés.

El tema es que me gustaría que al elegir el idioma me lleve a la misma página pero en inglés teniendo en cuenta la variable de la url que cambia ejemplo:

example.com/mi-primera-web y en inglés su url sería example.com/mi-first-web

La página no está enlazada a ninguna base de datos como os dije es básica.

el código del nav bar es este:

```
    <div class="navbar" id="myNavbar">
      <a href="/#home" class="active">Inicio</a>
      <a href="https://blog.example.org">Blog</a>
      <a href="https://forum.example.org">Foro</a>
      <a href="https://social.example.org">Social Cryptos</a>
      <a href="https://library.example.org">Biblioteca</a>
      <a href="https://support.example.org">¿Necesitas ayuda?</a>
      <a href="/en">English</a>
   <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:20px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
</div>
```

Como puedes ver el nav bar se inserta en todas las páginas así que desde donde esté me va a llevar siempre al index principal.
Lo que busco es `<a href="/en">English</a>` en esta línea colocar una variable que puedo poner en cada index para que se llame y lleve a la url respectiva del idioma selecionado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para utilizar una variable dentro de un href en PHP puedes utilizar:

```
<a href="<?php echo $variable;?>">English</a>
```

Dentro de $variable puedes insertar un string con "/en" o la forma en que quieras utilizar el redireccionamiento a la página en inglés. Recuerda que el archivo debe ser .php

Comment: Mil gracias,  llevaba varios días dando vueltas

Comment: Por favor @RobinRamirez si te sirvió la respuesta márcala como útil.